# How can I discover the original path for a missing SourceTree repository

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

In my SourceTree local repo list, I have an item flagged as "Repository Missing or Deleted". I need to know the path that is missing; it may help me remember what I did!

SourceTree must store the path to the local repository somewhere, hopefully readable. Where is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The local repository list is stored here:

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\bookmarks.xml